# Version control for MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, version-control

In my work I build MS Access databases.  I need to be able to compare two versions of the same database to see what has changed.  Version control.  I do not mean the data in the database.  I mean the forms, queries, modules etc that make up an Access database.

I currently manually write a description of what has changed in a module that just contains this “maintenance log” and use comments to denote the start and end of VBA code changes.

Does anybody know of any tools out there that can produce some kind of report or something else that shows what has changed from one version to the next?

Any ideas appreciated.